# How do I read a substring from a txt file?

Tags: powershell

```bash
(Select-String -Path "C:\Testfile\loadService.ini" -Pattern ("Server =(.*)", "DBName =(.*)")).Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

I want to output the information after `Server =` and `DbName=` and I cannot get this to run.

Answer (score 0):

as you have two patterns you have to get each value using `foreach`

```
(Select-String -Path ./test.ini -Pattern ("Server =(.*)","DbName =(.*)")).Matches | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Whenever capture groups are involved and more than one line matches, the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) objects that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs must be processed *one by one*.
- If `-AllMatches` *were* involved (it isn't here), you'd additionally have to process the entries of the `.Matches` collection one by one. In the absence of `-AllMatches` there is by definition only *one* match per matching line, stored in `.Matches[0]`

Therefore:

```bash
Select-String -Path "C:\Testfile\loadService.ini" -Pattern ("Server =(.*)", "DBName =(.*)") |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Note: Given that `$_.Matches` by definition only has 1 element, you could get away with omitting the `[0]` in this case, using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).

However, you can *not* use member enumeration directly on the multi-object `Select-String` output, as you've attempted (`(Select-String ...).Matches.Groups[1].Value`, because the nested `.Groups[1]` access would in effect only be applied *once*: `.Matches` returns a single, flat collection of match objects collected from the `.Matches` collections of the individual output objects, and `.Groups` then returns a single, flat collection of the `.Groups` property values from the first collection, to which `[1]` is then applied to extract the 2nd element.